# Can i use MIT, ISC, Apache-2.0 in a project licensed as MIT or Apache 2.0?

Tags: licensing, license-compatibility, mit, apache-2.0, isc

I want to create a project in Angular licensed as MIT or Apache 2.0 and i need to include projects with different licences (MIT, ISC, Apache-2.0 and perhaps BSD-3).

The project includes an area for credits with details (project, license, description):

1. [angular/angular](https://github.com/angular/angular) **MIT**
2. [tws/bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap) **MIT**
3. [ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap) **MIT**
4. [MrRio/jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) **MIT**
5. [mozilla/pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) **Apache 2.0**
6. [jakearchibald/idb](https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb) **ISC**
7. [electron/electron](https://github.com/electron/electron) **MIT**
8. [brix/crypto-js](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js) **MIT**

> ***mozilla/pdf.js*** is forked and modified, also it is included a link to
>   this fork.

- Can i use all this licenses in a project?
- Which is the best license for the project? MIT, Apache-2.0, ...?
- Are all licenses compatibles?
- Is BSD-3 compatible with MIT, ISC, Apache-2.0?
- Should I  have other considerations?

Answer (score 2):

The licenses of the projects you mention are all compatible with each other and the do not constrain which license you can choose for your own code. The BSD-3 license also falls into the same category.

You can freely choose which license to use for your code. It is hard to advise what license to use without knowing what you consider important in a license.